# I need help placing 3 div's next to each other with a text hover

Tags: html, hover

I am trying to place 3 images next together in a div.  To add to this complication is that I need to hid the image and reveal text when the mouse hovers over the image.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="TopRow">
<div class="TP">
<div class="TitleM">
  <a href="link">TP</a>
</div>
<div class="showcase">
<img src="image"   alt="TPM"/>
<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="link">>> Shop   </a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="SF">
<div class="TitleM">
  <a href="link">Stearns & Foster</a>
</div>
<div class="showcase">
<img src="image"   alt="TPM"/>
<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="link">>> Shop  </a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="VS">
<div class="TM">
  <a href="link">VS</a>
</div>
<div class="showcase">
<img src="image"   alt="TPM"/>
<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="link">>> Shop </a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
div.showcase {height: 241px; width: 300px; border: solid 1px #939598;}
div.showcase p {display: none;}
div.showcase:hover img {display: none;}
div.showcase:hover p {display: block;}

}
.TopRow {
height: auto;
width: 95%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
 }
.TP {
    Float:left;
height: auto;
width: 33%;

.V3 {
margin:0;
height: auto;
width: 33%;

.SF {
    Float:right;
height: auto;
width: 33%;
}
.TM {
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 125%;
background-color: #dce1e9;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #939598;
text-indent: 5px;
}
```

I know my issue is in the set size in showcase div, however I can not get things to line up correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formatting is so broken, I can't understand how you want it to be. You're missing brackets and your spacing is totally off

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to solve your problem in this fiddle: [Click me for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/fsvKD/1/)
I've also tried to clean your code up a bit as there were quite a few errors.

### HTML

```
<div class="TopRow">
    <div class="TP">
        <div class="TitleM">
            <a href="#">TP</a>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img src="http://osric.com/8ball/images/eight-ball.png" alt="TPM"/>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="link">>> Shop   </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SF">
        <div class="TitleM">
            <a href="#">Stearns &amp; Foster</a>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img src="http://osric.com/8ball/images/eight-ball.png"   alt="TPM"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="link">>> Shop  </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="VS">
        <div class="TM">
             <a href="#">VS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img src="http://osric.com/8ball/images/eight-ball.png"   alt="TPM"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="link">>> Shop </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.showcase {
    border: solid 1px #939598;
}
div.showcase p {
    visibility:hidden;
}
div.showcase:hover img {
    visibility:hidden;
}
div.showcase:hover p {
    visibility: visible;
}

body {
    margin:0;
}

.TopRow {
    width: 99%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.TP {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.VS {
    width:33%;    
    display:inline-block;
}
.SF {
    width: 33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```